# How to select column with json without sending column name?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm setting up an API with Node and postgreSQL-node (pg), and when I query for the column in my data base that contains JSON it returns an array of objects with the columns name and the json I want to access.

My current query is:

```
select jsondata 
from breweries
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "jsondata": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Avondale Brewing Co",
            "brewery_type": "micro",
            "street": "201 41st St S",
            "city": "Birmingham",
            "state": "Alabama",
            "postal_code": "35222-1932",
            "country": "United States",
            "longitude": "-86.774322",
            "latitude": "33.524521",
            "phone": "2057775456",
            "website_url": "http://www.avondalebrewing.com",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-23T23:19:57.825Z",
            "tag_list": []
        }
    },
    {"jsondata": {...}}, 
    {...}
]
```

My expectation is to get and array with the contents inside "jsondata" without the name of the column "jsondata", but I can't find a way to access it one level in my query.

Edit: 
Here is what I expect:

```
[
    {

            "id": 2,
            "name": "Avondale Brewing Co",
            "brewery_type": "micro",
            "street": "201 41st St S",
            "city": "Birmingham",
            "state": "Alabama",
            "postal_code": "35222-1932",
            "country": "United States",
            "longitude": "-86.774322",
            "latitude": "33.524521",
            "phone": "2057775456",
            "website_url": "http://www.avondalebrewing.com",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-23T23:19:57.825Z",
            "tag_list": []

    },
    {...}, 
    {...}
]
```

Comment: It looks like your `jsondata` field has an array of dictionaries within it.  You'd have to unnest that array and then the dictionary to get a regular list of "rows" like you're describing.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want? Please [edit] your question and add that as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exact output you're expecting, but you can convert the array of dictionaries to rows and then return the `jsondata` values as individual rows using this:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsondata)->'jsondata' 
FROM breweries
```

Is that along the lines of what you want?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/38771)

Comment: I get : error: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array

Comment: Can you please post the exact query you ran?  The one I posted above used `jsonb_array_elements`, although that's probably not related.

Comment: Also can you run this query and post the results: `SELECT PG_TYPEOF(jsondata) FROM breweries`?

Comment: Sure, pg_typeof(jsondata) is ```[
    {
        "pg_typeof": "json"
    },
    {
        "pg_typeof": "json"
    },{...}]```

Comment: and I ran ```SELECT json_array_elements(jsondata)->'jsondata' 
FROM breweries``` before instead of ```jsonb_array_elements```  because it was giving me the error ```error: function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist``` with a hint ```'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'```

Comment: hmm...ok.  It looks like you have `json` data, not `jsonb` so you are right to change to `json_array_elements`.  I copied the json output you posted into the SQL Fiddle and it works ok there, so I'm not sure.  What version of `Postgres` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 12, I think the problem is at my postgres-node library :/